# Java equivalent of tcp-inbound-channel-adapter and tcp-outbound-channel-adapter bean configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

Looking at the documentation: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/ip.html#tcp-adapters I understand that the adapters are for one way only communication. However, only XML configuration examples of these classes are given.

I am trying to configure them as Java beans, but I cannot find any documentation regarding how to do this. Please give me an example how I would configure the following in Java config:

```
<int-ip:tcp-outbound-channel-adapter
            id="outboundClient" channel="rsp_transformed" connection-factory="client" />

<int-ip:tcp-inbound-channel-adapter
            id="inboundClient" channel="req" connection-factory="client" client-mode="true" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [Annotations on Beans](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/configuration.html#annotations_on_beans).

In 4.3 we have added class information the XML schema for the [inbound](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/spring-integration-ip/src/main/resources/org/springframework/integration/ip/config/spring-integration-ip-4.3.xsd#L143) and [outbound](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/spring-integration-ip/src/main/resources/org/springframework/integration/ip/config/spring-integration-ip-4.3.xsd#L216) endpoints.

In this case, the inbound adapter is simply a `TcpReceivingChannelAdapter` `@Bean`, the outbound adapter is a `TcpSendingMessageHandler` annotated with `@ServieActivator` - the framework uses the information in the annotation to create a `ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean` to support the handler.

You should also look at the [Java DSL](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl) which makes java configuration simpler in many cases.